# WooCommerce - Hide products which has not image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to hide all products in woocommerce which have no image.

Can anyone know the appropriate solution as per my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: "hide"? hide where?

Comment: From website front-end side only

Comment: Do you want hide products  in shop page or any other page?Please mention on which page you want to hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code... There can be ways to do it and this is one.

```
function woocommerce_product_query( $q ) {
    $q->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woocommerce_product_query' );
```

This will just make sure `_thumbnail_id` has a value.

Make sure your product has this empty.
[image]

---

For more general code, please use this

```
function pre_get_posts( $q ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && ( $q->get('post_type') == 'product' ) ) {
       $q->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts' );
```

But you should be careful with this, because it will also apply to all product type query in the frontend. You might get unexpected result, that's why there's a lot in the `if` statement but might need more.

Comment: I am not clear about your answer. If possible then provide some detail clarification

Comment: put that code in your current theme's functions.php or put it on a plugin if you want...

Comment: Yes I have added but without products images,  products are not hide

Comment: do you have a link I could check? this should hide those products that uses "placeholder.jpg" if your theme is using another or setting the thumbnail with some default, this won't work..

Comment: Not hide from related products

Comment: remove the `if` part.. use only `$q->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );`

Comment: Don't worry I have fixed it another way. But Thanks For help

Comment: you should update your post to what fixes it. This should help others that has same problem as yours

Answer (score 1):

There are so many `hooks and filters` available in WooCommerce. You can use them and modify or update functionality.

[Action and Filter Hook Reference in WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

Please use hook `woocommerce_product_query` to modify your query as :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'noimage_pre_get_posts_query' );
function noimage_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {

    $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '0',
       'compare' => '>'
    )));

}
```

Put this in `functions.php` file of the theme in WordPress

Comment: Your code is work for hiding products from related products result in detail page.? Please clarify