# How to get all products that doesn't have feature image in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

some of my products missing their images, what I'm trying to do is to make a query that will give me only products with the default image (woocommerce place holder image).

this is what i have tried :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query', array( 
            array(
               'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
               'value' => '5',
               'compare' => '=='
            )
        )
    );
```

i found place holder image id using this function :

```
attachment_url_to_postid("/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder.png");
```

the query returns every single product I have, and not only those with the placeholder image, what causes it, and is there a better way?

Comment: Did you verify that ID you found for the placeholder image, is actually contained in the `_thumbnail_id` meta entry for those products?

Comment: @CBroe i just checked and those product does not have any value in _thumbnail_id , so i tried to change the value in the meta query to null, still getting all the products instead the wanted only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce - Hide products which has not image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809244/woocommerce-hide-products-which-has-not-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check using `meta_key` `_thumbnail_id`. Try the below query.

```
global $wpdb;

$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE ID NOT IN (
        SELECT post_id from $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
    ) 
    AND post_type = 'product' 
    AND post_status = 'publish'
" );

echo "<pre>"; print_r( $post_ids ); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: working, may i ask what is the logic behind the query ?

Comment: @davidasor apparently the `_thumbnail_id` is not NULL for these products, as you said - but a record with the meta_key `_thumbnail_id` does not even _exist_ in the meta data table. And this filters out all products, that _have_ such a record.

Comment: understood, thanks a lot!